# Deltaspike service layer catching PersistenceException unexpected behavior

Tags: cdi, deltaspike

I have a java ee 8 web app using deltaspike using core, data and jsf modules.

I also added cdi bean (RegisterService using @trasactional) which calls a UserRepository

```
public void createNewUser(User newUser){
      try{
         userRepository.save(newUser) 
      }catch(PersistenceException ex){
          throw new RegisterException("Error", ex); //it never falls at this point
      }
}
```

When service layer calls repository I’m catching a PersistenceException and rethrowing a service layer exception but the repository never throws PersistenceException even if the primary ID is duplicated (I just can see the stacktrace in console output), of course I’m running into a contraint exception to try to execute the expected flow

I’m using a deltaspike exception handler but I have not added a @handler for PersistenceException

Does somebody knows what could be happening here?

this is a reproducible example: https://github.com/gdiazs/javaee8-fullstack

Since there is no tables in DB it will throw an PersitenceException.

**I ran this example in 2 laptops.**

```
Mine: OSx 10.14.6
JDK: Open JDK Zulu 1.8
eclipse and also maven terminal execution

Work: OSx 10.14.6 (it works as I expect good here)
JDK: Oracle 1.8
Intellij and also maven terminal execution
```

So now I`m really confused, no idea why is working just in one.

Comment: What do you mean by _"but the repository exception never happens"_?

Comment: Ok, clear now. What is the deltaspike version and can you create a [mcve]? I'm thinking of using deltaspike data also and like to experiment

Comment: Hey!, sorry bad sentence. This is happening because I'm using deltaspike exception handling (I guess) I'm just trying to re throw a `RegisterException` but even if the repository throws a real persistence exception  the catch is not working as expected, I just got PersistenceException in logs

Comment: Cool @Kukeltje, I'm at job right now and I'll need a bit of time to build the example.

I'm using deltaspike 1.9.1
and tomee 8

Comment: I think that I have an example, but seems I cant reproduce the problem, it actually runs well, but I've used a tomee for Java EE 7 instead of java ee8 where I have the issue, so maybe that's the problem. 

So I'll change it in order to have the same tomee version and see what if the the problem appears. if it does, so I better push this problem to the delta spike jira

Comment: great work. That  is what [mcve]'s are for. Including easy testing on different platforms

Comment: @Kukeltje I just leave an example, if you have problems to running it just reach me.
skype (memoxds)

Comment: Hi, it might be reproducible example, but I doubt it is minimal. Does it work without bootsfaces? Without a layout? With one page instead of 2? Without message properties, without a web.xml? Normally a [mcve] shoud fit in the question.

Comment: But I'll try tomorrow (what do I need to do to reproduce?)

Comment: start the app, go to the home page and follow the link and submit the form. It should throw a RegisterException. On one of my laptops works good. 

https://github.com/gdiazs/javaee8-fullstack/blob/master/src/main/java/io/github/gdiazs/javaee8/register/RegisterService.java